# jquery modal getting it to close when I click elsewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, modal-dialog

at the moment Im only learning javascript and could do with some help here as Im a little confused as to where to go from here.
I have a site with a modal using jquery, I can get it to show when I click on the image, but when I click elsewhere it doesnt turn it off. 
Ive tried toggle, but that makes it turn on and off no matter where I click.
Ive tried hide but that stops it working at all (assuming its applying the hide function even when I click on the link)
Heres what I have so far, any help would be great...

```
jQuery('#youtube').click(function(){
jQuery('#youtubemodal').show();
});
```

Comment: I found a solution, which I think looks nicer anyway, I created a div with a dark background that loads when I click the youtube image. Im then forced to click this background when Im clicking elsewhere and I have a hide function applied both to that and the modal when I click it.

Answer (score 0):

make an function that checks for youtubemodal that is shown and then hide.

```
$("document").click(function() {
    if( $('#youtubemodal').is(':visible') ) {
        $('#youtubemodal').hide();
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks TWCrap, but that doesnt seem to have worked, it doesnt seem to be recognising the fact that it is visible, so when I click elsewhere nothing happens

Comment: And put an alert in the document.click funtion (not in the if) so you can see that the function is triggerd. And if that is so, do the same in the if statement...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

```
$('#youtube').click(function(){
    $('#youtubemodal')
        .show()
        .on("click", function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    $(document).on("click.youtubemodal", function(){
        $(this).off(".youtubemodal");
        $('#youtubemodal').hide();
    });
});​
```

This is how it will behave:

- When you click on the image, the modal appears
- When the modal appears, we add a listener to `document` so that when you click *anywhere*, the modal is hidden (and the listener is removed as well)
- When the modal appears, we also add a listener to it, so that if you click on the modal if doesn't hide it: the modal is only hidden if you click outside of it

Note: if you're not using jQuery 1.7 or above, replace `.on()` with `.bind()`, and `.off()` with `.unbind()`

Comment: Thanks for that , but that didnt work either unfortunately :(

Comment: Please post all your code then (at least the HTML for `#youtube` and `#youtubemodal`)

Comment: hi Pioul,  I have posted a workaround for it above, but thanks for the help and explanation!

Comment: No problem. Instead of a comment, you might want to post this workaround as an answer and accept it (with some code to quickly show what you did to people who have the same question).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with my own workaround for this, where I set up a div with a dark background with an opacity of 40%,that appears throughout the page when the modal is loaded.

```
#modalbackground {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-image: url('images/modalbackground.png');
background-repeat: repeat;
position:fixed;
z-index:600;
display:none;

}
```

I then put this div outside of everything to insure it covers the entire page

```
<div id="modalbackground"> </div>
```

I then applied this code to make sure the div and the modal closes when I click on the new dark "background".

```
jQuery('#youtube').click(function(){
jQuery('#youtubemodal').show();

});

jQuery('#youtube').click(function(){
jQuery('#modalbackground').show();

});

jQuery('#modalbackground').click(function(){
jQuery('#modalbackground').hide();
});

jQuery('#modalbackground').click(function(){
jQuery('#youtubemodal').hide();
});
```